# Find $\dot{x}$ and $\ddot{x}$ of $x(t) = e^{-\gamma t}\:\cos \left(\omega \:t\right) x(0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification

I am trying to find the first and second derivative of a function
$$
x(t) = e^{-\gamma t}\:\cos \left(\omega \:t\right) x(0)
$$

i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \:t}\left(e^{-\gamma \:t\:}\:\cos \left(\omega \:t\right)\right) \ \ \ \& \\ \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \:t^2}\left(e^{-\gamma \:t\:}\:\cos \left(\omega \:t\right)\right)
$$
I have some solutions below and would like to check if they are correct and if not what is the correct solution?

***My solution***
$$
\dot{x} = - \gamma e^{- \gamma t} \cos{\left (\omega t \right )} - \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin{\left (\omega t \right )}
$$

$$
\ddot{x} = \gamma^{2} e^{- \gamma t} \cos{\left (\omega t \right )} - 2 \gamma \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin{\left (\omega t \right )} - \omega^{2} e^{- \gamma t} \cos{\left (\omega t \right )}
$$

Comment: Why you you use *partial* derivatives?

Comment: It should be $\ddot{x} = \color{red}+ 2 \gamma \omega e^{-\gamma t} \sin(\omega t) + ... $.

Comment: Is the $x(0)$ term a typo? If not, all the terms of the derivatives should be multiplied by $x(0)$. Also, as mentioned, it should be $\color{red}{+}2\gamma w\ldots$

Comment: $x(0)$ is the initial condition, this is an ODE.

Comment: @user4933, but you don't give any value for the initial condition. It's just multiplied with $e^{-\gamma t}\cos(\omega t)$. Perhaps you meant $x(t)=e^{-\gamma t}\cos(\omega t)$ with $x(0)=\textrm{some value}$?

Comment: This is part of a question in Kurt Jacobs, Stochastic processes for physicists on page 24, part of question 1. If I understand it properly the initial condition of this ODE is $x(0)$

Answer (score 1):

$$x=e^{-gt} \cos wt \implies x'=-g e^{-gt} \cos w t- e^{-gt} w \sin wt=-(g\cos wt+w \sin wt)e^{-gt}$$
$$x''=-(-g w \sin wt+w^2\cos wt)e^{-gt}+g(g \cos w t+w \sin wt)e^{-gt}$$
$$x''=[(g^2-w^2) \cos wt +2gw \sin wt]e^{-gt}.$$